# TypeScript AMD modules. Names and namespaces.

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with naming my AMD modules. What is best practice for doing it?

For example IProfileService.ts:

```
export interface IProfileService {
    savePersonalInfo(): void;
}
```

In my controller file:

```
import ps = module('../contracts/IPersonalInfoScope');
import pf = module('../contracts/IProfileService');

export class PersonalInfoCtrl {    
    ...    
    constructor(
        private $scope: ps.IPersonalInfoScope,
        private profileService: pf.IProfileService
        ) {...};
    };
    ...
}
```

So, the problem that I need to create for each my interface, class, etc. such sub name: **ps, pf** because I have one class/interface per file. Can I do something like this: **contracts.IPersonalInfoScope, contracts.IProfileService** without puting them to one file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not since the only way to merge these two types (`ps` and `pf`) is with a variable. But a variable is in the variable declaration space and cannot be used to declare a type. i.e. you cannot:

```
var x = {a:123,b:123};
var y:x; // Error
```

More: http://basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/declarationspaces